# Velocity of scrollRect always returns (0.0,0.0)

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollrect

In the documentation it says that ScrollRect has a velocity variable. (http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect.html)

But if I try to tap into it or output it to the console using the following code

```
 Debug.Log("Velocity: " + scroll.velocity.ToString());
```

the only output I get is

```
 Velocity: (0.0, 0.0)
 UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

Has anyone managed to get a value from this variable? Any advice on what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you get different output when you scroll the content of the ScrollRect?

Comment: No I get the vector (0.0,0.0) no matter how much I move the ScrollRect?
The Debug.Log is in a fixed update function, by the way.

Comment: Is there enough content in the ScrollRect such that it can scroll? i.e. does the content of the ScrollRect overflow?

Comment: Yes the scrollRect functions brilliantly, it scrolls a panel three times it's width left and right. But the velocity doesn't return anything? I am just trying to get the speed and direction of the scrollRect to trigger events.

Comment: It appears that `velocity` is not implemented properly, though the only reference to this I can find is [this forum post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/infinite-scroll-with-scrollrect.265345/#post-1754337). Perhaps they have not yet exposed it. What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Unity 4.2.6f1. So you think this is a bug, that is awaiting fixture in 5?

Comment: I think so. The post I linked is from August, so it'd be my bet that this was fixed in 5, if at all.